# Nested Threading in Android (Thread within thread)

Tags: android, multithreading, nested

Is it advisable to implement nested threading?? I'm across a situation where I need to call a thread within thread. I'm having other options too, like implementing all the methods within the same thread, but it becomes too untidy. The project is half-way gonna be taken over by someone else, so the other person might have a hard time getting all stuff together.

Also is it advisable to call multiple threads, within a thread (for the same reason as above).

Would it affect the performance in any way (logically, it should improve the performance, since the software is intended for a dual core device)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting answer from @kabuko, @Fuzzical Logic and doing some research, I figured out that nested-threading isn't really possible using AsyncTask as such, since the AsyncTask needs to be executed within a UI thread.
However, what I was trying to implement could be done by:

- In the initial UI thread, call different,multiple AsyncTask to be executed.

  Example:

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {.....

  DownloadUpdates.execute(fileId); //AsyncTask # 1

  UpdateNotification.execute();  //AsyncTask # 2

  ......}

**Note** (as given in the document [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)):

> A single task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown
>   if a second execution is attempted)

- *However, avoid using any such logic if the two threads are interdependent, since its time of execution is unpredictable, and it
  may go into deadlock or something.*
- *Also, nested threading is also possible using normal threading (not using AsyncTask) as noted by @Fuzzical Logic*

Comment: Nested threading certainly is possible. However, nested AsyncTasks are not. Further, the note you cite above refers to running the same AsyncTask more than once. @kabuko states that in most cases, multiple AsyncTasks can actually be more efficient than nested threading. If you need further help understanding the semantics, let me know.

Comment: @Fuzzical noted, and thank you. I think what I wanted to implement, i did get it right. But anyways, thank you for the support.

Comment: @Fuzzical Logic :I did write that I implemented it by calling multiple AsyncTask in the main UI thread. But yeah, I'll add a small snippet along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new threads causes a bit more hassle for you to deal with, so generally I would advise you not to manually create a new thread just for the sake of separating things.

If you have fairly distinct chunks of work that you want process outside of the main UI thread, there are [easier ways of dealing with threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). Consider putting them into `AsyncTask`s and if you want to run multiple tasks concurrently you can make sure the executor they run on has a larger-than-one thread pool size.

It's hard to say exactly what the right approach is without a little more detail as to what your problem actually is.

Comment: well, I just want to keep things simple and improve the efficiency of the program.
if I call all the methods within a single thread, then it might take too long to execute. So I would like all of the methods to run simultaneously, so that processing time is less. And as it is, there  is no relation between the methods, so the order in which the methods in nested threads gets implemented doesn't matter. 

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Yep, sure. That makes sense if you have some processing to do. Take a look at the article I linked, especially the use of `AsyncTask`. It addresses easier ways to deal with this than manually creating and managing threads.

Comment: Actually, using AsyncTask is how I was planning to implement it. I was gonna call some "new DownloadUpdates.execute(fileId)" and "new UpdateNotification.execute()" within the doInBackground of another thread. The developer.android.com doesn't talk about nesting, that is why I put my question here. But now, since you are since its advisable, I'll go ahead with it. Thank You.

Comment: Actually for `AsyncTask` you have to create and execute it on the UI thread. You can't do it in `doInBackground`. See the threading rules section of the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: oh ya, guess I skipped that part while reading the doc before. Thanks. So, in short, nested threading, as such, isn't possible. Damn!! Thanks anyways.